# Can we customize the facebook review to include more fields

Tags: facebook, customization, review

In facebook review page we just have Ratings, Comments field. How to include some more custom fields like category, product etc. Or can we get the feedback in our web page and post it to facebook?

Answer (score 0):

> In facebook review page we just have Ratings, Comments field. How to include some more custom fields like category, product etc.

There is no way to do that. Facebook specifies, which fields are available.

> Or can we get the feedback in our web page and post it to facebook?

Not possible either.

---

(Nearly all platforms showing any kind of customer / user reviews have problems with fake reviews and spam. Allowing to feed reviews into the system from the outside would just increase the possibilities that malicious apps abuse this, and post fake reviews without the users being aware.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Can anyone please share the link which has the facebook api sample to get the reviews of a page or any documentation in Java

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link